# Sharepoint adding lookup column to a webpart chart

Tags: sharepoint

We have two content types (elements and divisions for example).

In the element's list, we have a field which lookup on divisions title field N:N.
So for example we have the element TestElement-1, with a lookup field with these values: Division-1, Division-2 and Division-3.

Creating a webpart chart (using Excel Access) with this Element list as database, we can't see this lookupfield column.

However, if this lookupfield is only N:1 (one single division value for each lookup field on element), it shows the corresponding related id.

Any solution for the N:N?

Kind Regards.

Comment: You need to be more clear and probably provide an example of work

Comment: Hope now it's more clear